# What is your expectation of the depth?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cohomology, local-cohomology

Let $S=k[x_1,...,x_9]$ be a polynomial ring over field $k$. Set $q_1=(x_1,x_2,x_5,x_6)$, $q_2=(x_1,x_2,x_6,x_7)$, $q_3=(x_2,x_3,x_7,x_8)$, $q_4=(x_1,x_5,x_6,x_7)$, $q_5=(x_1,x_6,x_7,x_8)$, $q_6=(x_2,x_6,x_7,x_8)$, $I=(x_1,..,x_4)$. How to compute $\operatorname{Depth}_I(S/\cap_{i=1}^{6}q_i)$? in general, Is there a way to compute $\operatorname{Depth}_I(S/\cap_{i=1}^{t}q_i)$ when $S=k[x_1,...,x_n]$, $q_i=(x_{i_1},...,x_{i_r})$? Is there any algorithm to compute it (using Macaulay2)?

background:

the common length of the maximal $M$-sequences in $I$ is called the grade of $I$ on $S$-module $M$ denoted by $\operatorname{Depth}_I(M)$.

Comment: Use Macaulay 2.

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin I wanna comput it manually.

Comment: In order to get people motivated you may want to add answers to the questions like: What is your expectation of the depth? Why is this question interesting to you, or where is this question coming from? If it is just your own curiosity, then I guess mathstackexchange might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin , I think that Macauly2 can not compute it.

Comment: I just used Macaulay2 to compute it.  Macaulay asserts it has Depth = 2.  I can post the Macaulay2 code here as an answer if you'd like.  (Make sure to load the "Depth" package).

Comment: Another thing to consider / google.  All your ideals are monomials.  There may be some good algorithms to compute this (have you tried googling these terms?)

Comment: @KarlSchwede, Really,M2 can compute grade(I,M)?

Comment: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.6/share/doc/Macaulay2/Depth/html/_depth_lp__Ideal_cm__Ring_rp.html